# Push Notification : Move to Specific View on Tap of Notification in Kill Mode in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, push-notification, appdelegate, usernotifications

I am using **Push Notifications** in my SwiftUI app. The thing I need is when I tap on the notification I have to open a **specific View**. This is working fine when the app is in **foreground** or in **background** mode. But when the app is been **killed** and then I tap on the notification, it only opens the app and it doesn't go to that specified View.

Here is what I tried.

My code in AppDelegate:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                              didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                              withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo

      if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
          print("Message ID from userNotificationCenter didReceive: \(messageID)")
      }
      print(userInfo)
      
      DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
              
              NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("request_notification"), object: nil, userInfo: userInfo)
           
      }
      
      completionHandler()
  }
```

And in my ContentView:

```
struct ContentView: View {
 
  @State var msgId = ""
  @State var moveToNextView = false
 
     var body: some View {

           VStack {

                     Text("Content View")                  

                 }.background(hiddenNav())
             .onAppear {
           
                NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: Notification.Name("message_notification"), object: nil, queue: .main) { notification in
            
                  print(notification)
                  let userInfo = notification.userInfo
                  self.msgId = userInfo["message_id"] as? String   // this gives me my message_id = 01
                  self.moveToNextView.toggle()
                 }
             }
    }

       func hiddenNav() -> some View {
            ZStack {
                NavigationLink("", destination: NotificationsView(msgId: self.msgId), isActive: $moveToNextView)
            
        }
    }
}
```

What I need is, when the app is been **killed** and then I tap on notification, it should take me to my **specified View**.